# Using multiple files from a directory with a scanner (Java)

Tags: java, file, directory, java.util.scanner

I'm trying to read from multiple .txt files in a directory using a scanner in Java.

So far, I have

```j
File directory = new File("textanalyzer/Shakespeare");
        File[] filenames = directory.listFiles();

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File(filenames)).useDelimiter("[^a-zA-Z<]+");
```

The rest of my program uses the text from these files. I have the rest of the program written but I'm stuck on this one thing.

I've been looking around for a solution, but I can't really find anything. I know that what I have isn't very good but I don't know enough Java to be able to improve it. I've also tried using Apache imports but I can't figure out how to make them work (FileIterator, in particular).

Finally, I would really like to use the Scanner class so that I can use the Delimiter. It is super helpful for what I'm trying to do.

Comment: I did not understand your issue?!!!!! how many txt file are you trying to read?

Comment: I can't see where the problem is.  Are you trying to loop through every file and having trouble with that?

Comment: Yeah, I'm trying to get information from each file. Sorry. I've been looking at this for way too long. Ugh.

Comment: so we have already knew that you want to do this, but you said you have some diffuclty for your delimiters ? what is issue regarding to that? how many file are they? please explain more so we can help you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not quite sure what your goal is but this basic example might help.

```
      File[] fileArray=new File("textanalyzer/Shakespeare").listFiles();        

        for(File f: fileArray) // loop thru all files
        {

           if(f.getName().endsWith(".txt")) // to deal with the .txt files.
            {                 
             Scanner s=new Scanner(f); // to read the files

            }              

        }
```

Comment: Thank you, that is actually exactly what I was looking for. :)

Comment: No problem. I think others were wanting to understand your end goal to help more, as was myself. Next time just explain more in detail about the end results, such as why you want to use delimiters and how do you plan on dealing with the scanner results.